# jquery ajax: newbie question

Tags: jquery, ajax

1. A file called test containing the following line:

   [{"foo":"abc","bar":"01"},{"foo":"def","bar":"02"}]
2. jquery ajax:

   $.ajax({
       url: "test",
       success: function(data) {....

Stupid question maybe, but shouldnt i be able to get the values in the function with something like `data.foo` ? Never used ajax before as you might have figured out :)

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you can't exactly call `data.foo` because your `data` object is actually an array of objects, so you would access its properties with `data[0].foo`, `data[1].foo` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would be able, the `[{"foo":"abc","bar":"01"},{"foo":"def","bar":"02"}]` data structure is called `json` and jQuery parses it without problem, it even has a specific method for json [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). See examples here:

http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/How-to-Use-JSON-with-jQuery-AJAX

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html